# On morphisms of pure Hodge structures of decreasing weight

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $H_{\mathbf{Q}}$ and $H_{\mathbf{Q}}'$ be two pure Hodge structures of weight $n$ and
$n'$ respectively. How do you prove the following simple fact:

**fact:** If $n>n'$ and $f:H_{\mathbf{Q}}\rightarrow H_{\mathbf{Q}}'$ is a morphism which respects the filtrations over $\mathbf{C}$, then $f=0$.

I don't quite see how to use the assumption $n>n'$...

**added**

My original question was related to the fact that asking the morphism to be compatible with the torus action seems to be a stronger condition that only asking for the filtration to be preserved. And I guess that in general this is all you can say. This reflexion was motivated by Deligne Scholie 5.1 in Hodge 1 which says the following:

**Scholie 5.1** Soit $H$ et $H'$ des structures de Hodge de poids $n$ et $n'$ avec $n>n'$.Soit $f:H_{\mathbf{Q}}\rightarrow H_{\mathbf{Q}}'$ un morphisme tel que $f:H_C\rightarrow H_C'$ respecte $F$. Alors $f=0$.

**Q:** So how should I interpret Scholie 5.1?

Comment: One only needs to assume that $n \neq n'$...

Comment: It's easier if you think that a weight HS has a 
bigrading  $H\otimes \C$ with $\bar H^{pq}=H^{qp}$ and $p+q=n$.
Since morphisms must preserve this, they would vanish for different
weights. There is a lemma to be proved about the equivalence of
this notion with representations of Deligne's torus, but it's not difficult.

Comment: Well I have a counter-example to what you said take 
$H_{\mathbf{C}}=\mathbf{C}$ place in degree $(0,0)$ and take
$H_{\mathbf{C}}=\mathbf{C}$ place in degree $(1,1)$.

Comment: My comment was meant to @Ulrich


Comment: Well may be I'm confused but take $H_{Q}=Q$ and $H_{Q}'=Q$ with the identity map $\iota: H_Q\rightarrow H_{Q'}$. If you place 
$H_Q$ in degree $(0,0)$ and $H_{Q}'$ in degree $(1,1)$ then this respects the Hodge filtration, isn't ? 

Comment: The lemma (although not the proof) of my earlier comment is
on page 25 of "Théorie de Hodge II".

Comment: So you see I'm not asking that my map respects the torus action but simply that it respects the Hodge filtration which is somehow weaker

Comment: Perhaps I understand the confusion, but I'm still not quite sure.
A morphism defined over $\mathbb{Q}$,
and in particular over $\mathbb{R}$, preserving the Hodge filtration $F$,   must also preserve the conjugate $\bar F$. But
$H^{pq}= F^p\cap \bar F^{q}$. So we are back to the my earlier point.
The key point is the pair $(F,\bar F)$ are what Deligne calls opposed
filtrations, and this leads to special features.
Does this help?


Comment: So going back to my example we find that $F^k H_{C}=C$ if $k\leq 0$
and $0$ if $k>0$. Similarly we find that $H_{\mathbf{C}}'=\mathbf{C}$
if $k\leq 1$ and $0$ if $k>1$. Therefore for all $k$ we have that
$F^k H_{\mathbf{C}}\subseteq F^k H_{\mathbf{C}}'$.



Comment: I claim that there are no nonzero morphisms (= $\mathbb{Q}$-linear
filtered maps) from $\mathbb{Q}$ and the Tate twist $\mathbb{Q}(-1)$
(your example). But I'm afraid I'm going to have to leave this to you.



Comment: Well I'll try to resolve my confusion, any way thanks Donu. 

Comment: @Hugo: I think you are right. I was confused by your use of the word morphism. There are no morphisms of (mixed) Hodge structures between pure Hodge structures of different weights but what you define is not a morphism (in the sense of Deligne) since there is no condition on the weight filtration.

Comment: Well, I never talked about mixed Hodge structure but only pure Hodge structure so there is no Galois action and therefore no weight filtration

Comment: So in my question I'm only asking for a morphism of Hodge structure. My point is that a map which respects the torus action seems to be stronger than a map which only respects the filtration.

Comment: I hadn't read that before. Scholie 5.1 is baffling to me as well,
since a few lines up, Deligne makes a stronger statement
"si $f:H\to H'$ un morphisme de structures de Hodge mixte pures
de poids différents, alors $f$ torsion."  If you figure it
out, let us know.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the Scholie is correct: $f$ is NOT a morphism of Hodge structures but just a linear map of the underlying rational vector spaces which, when based changed to $\mathbb{C}$, preserves $F$. (For pure Hodge structures of a fixed weight $n$ this is a morphism of Hodge structures.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of the Scholie:

For a pure Hodge structure $H$ of weight $n$ we have $H_{\mathbb{C}} = \oplus_{p+q=n} H^{p,q}$ where we have $H^{p,q} := F^p \cap \bar{F}^q$. The key point is that $H^{p,q}$ as defined above is $0$ if $p+q > n$ (but not if $p+q < n$). This is because for a pure Hodge structure of weight $n$ we have $F^p = \oplus_{p' \geq p, p' +q' = n} H^{p',q'}$ and $\bar{F}^q = \oplus_{q' \geq q, p' + q' = n} H^{p',q'}$.

The Scholie now follows easily: It suffices to prove that $f(H^{p,q}) = 0$ for all $p+q = n$. Since $f$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, $f(H^{p,q}) \subset H'^{p,q}$ and the latter is $0$ if $n > n'$.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I somehow mislead myself into believing that
filtered $\mathbb{Q}$-linear maps between pure Hodge structures
are morphisms, but this only true if the weights are the same.
Sometimes the obvious interpretation is the hardest.


Comment: .... to accept.

Comment: But Ulrich I'm confused, you only seem to use the fact that $n\neq n'$ and moreover what about my counterexample 

Comment: You have $f(F^P H)\subseteq F^p H'$ but I don't quite see how you get 
from that $f(H^{p,q})\subseteq H'^{p,q}$. In fact my counterexample shows that it is wrong, isn't?

Comment: Since $f$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (so commutes with complex conjugation) one also gets $f(\bar{F}^qH) \subset \bar{F}^q H'$. Your counterexample doesn't apply here since the conclusion uses $n > n'$.


Comment: Ok Ulrich, I got it. I was too quick with your key remark: The key point is that $H^{p,q}$ as defined above is $0$ if $p+q>n$ **but not if $p+q<n$**. Thanks a lot for clearing out my confusion.